# Curiosidad formulario laravel con fieldset

Tags: html, laravel

Tengo una pequeña duda que me gustaria resolver y la verdad por internet no me dejan nada claro.
Tengo un formulario ( en este caso donde me falla es para recuperar contraseña), el cual tiene todos sus divs y demas elementos necesarios para hacer la validación de la contraseña y restablecerla:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-simple" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

Bien, con este formulario todo funciona correcto, pero cuando trato de implementar mi template, me dice que la confirmación de contraseña no es correcta, y todo por cambiar los divs, por fieldset para organizar la vista un poco mejor. Mi formulario personalizado es el siguiente:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-simple" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" name ="email" id="email" placeholder="Introduzca su email" value="{{old('email')}}">
                <div class="form-control-position"><i class="icon-head"></i></div>
                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @endif
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña nueva" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg " required confirmed>
                <div class="form-control-position"><i class="icon-key3"></i></div>
                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                    @endif
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" name="password-confirm" id="password-confirm" placeholder="Repita contraseña" required confirmed>
            <div class="form-control-position"><i class="icon-key3"></i></div>
                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
                @endif
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><i class="icon-unlock2"></i>Restablecer contraseña </button>
        @include('errors.flash-message')
</form>
```

He leído que hay que añadirle un campo a los fieldset para que te los coja como validaciones, pero no me ha funcionado, en verdad me da un poco igual si consigo hacerlo funcionar porque es mera curiosidad, pero he de reconocer que es un poco frustrante.

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es el nombre del campo de confirmar contraseña, debe ser `name="password_confirm"`, pusiste `name="password-confirm"`

Comment: pues mira que le he dado vueltas, y mira que cambie mil veces el id y nombres y nada... hasta estube leyendo que el fieldset necesitaba un campo especial para ser confirmed o algo asi... si es que hay que ser burro -.-''' muchas gracias.